Passing commands through the Terminal window in Python
I need to both open a new terminal window, and then pass different commands through this window to run a file. I am running this on macOS and have already done pip3 install applescript
What I currently have is
import os
import applescript
command1 = 'cd Documents'
command2 = 'cd codefolder'
command3 = 'python3 newgame.py'
os.system('open -a Terminal .')
applescript.tell.app('Terminal', 'do script "' + command1 + '"')
applescript.tell.app('Terminal', 'do script "' + command2 + '"')
applescript.tell.app('Terminal', 'do script "' + command3 + '"')

I run this by going into terminal and typing cd Documents then typing python3 runfile.py
The problem that I am running into is that 4 different Terminal windows are appearing and then errors occur. For clarification, "codefolder" "newgame.py" and "runfile.py" are all names of folders and files that are in Documents.

Why not just cd Documents/codefolder && python newgame.py?

I don't think do script is something you tell the Terminal app to do. It's a generic AppleScript command, not specific to an app.

I cant go directly from Documents to newgame.py because newgame.py is in codefolder

could i do cd Documents && cd codefolder && python3 newgame.py ? OK nevermind it worked, thanks.

Why do you think it's better to do two cd commands instead of one? They mean the same thing.

i didnt know that i was able to merge the two cd commans, i will fix that

as Barmar said; you can use && to go into several directories at the same time.
the final code i found to work is
import applescript
command = 'cd Documents/codefolder && python3 newgame.py'
applescript.tell.app('Terminal', 'do script "' + command + '"')

note: make sure you have done pip3 install applescript
